# Error while saving data to data table in Pega PRPC

Tags: pega

While saving data in Pega PRPC using activity with Obj-save method, I got following error message:
**pyCommitError: A commit cannot be performed because a deferred save of instance ANDY-FW-ANDYCARRENTALFW-DATA-CARINFO L3 failed: code:  SQLState:  Message:**

Can anyone share some idea on how to fix this issue?

Andy

Answer (score 0):

This message could come when we have a field which has a less field length specified in DB and we are trying to insert bigger string in the field.
There could be other reasons as well.See Tracer.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I got it work now. Tracer as you suggested is really helpful. The reason is quite simple, the instance was locked.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred save of instance usually fails due to locked instance which you are trying to commit. Or the record you are trying to commit is stale (someone else committed before your commit)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this behavior can be observed because of the lock on the work object not being held while you are trying to save the object. Make sure you acquire the lock before updating and save.

Additionally please check if privilege is given to the operator.